# copying azure blob to azure fileshare, using Python SDK

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-files

I'm trying to copy a blob from Azure storage blob container to a file share, running the following script on Azure Databricks

```
dbutils.library.installPyPI('azure-storage-blob')
dbutils.library.installPyPI('azure-storage-file-share')
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient, ShareFileClient

connection_string = my_connection_string

blobserviceclient = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string) 
source_blob = BlobClient(blobserviceclient.url,container_name = 'my-container-name', blob_name = 'my_file.json')

fileshareclient = ShareClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, 'my-fileshare-name')
destination_file= fileshareclient.get_file_client('my_file.json')

destination_file.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url)
```

I get the following error:

```
ResourceNotFoundError: The specified resource does not exist.
```

When I check for source_blob.url and destination_file.url, they both exist:

```
source_blob.url
'https://myaccountname.file.core.windows.net/my-container-name/my_file.json'
```

and

```
destination_file.url
'https://myaccountname.file.core.windows.net/my-fileshare-name/my_file.json'
```

I used the examples from this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-share/samples/file_samples_client.py
Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
This works when I use AzCopy.
I can also copy from one blob container to another, just not from the blob container to file share.

Comment: You would need to create a SAS URL for the source blob and use that in your `start_copy_from_url` method.

Comment: I'm using the account key in the connection string, though. Isn't that enough?

Comment: @SabaFar, when copying, the resource must be public or using url+sastoken. If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer. Thanks:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `sasToken` with the blob url when using the method `start_copy_from_url` or [set the source blob container as public](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/anonymous-read-access-configure?tabs=portal#set-the-public-access-level-for-a-container). Otherwise, it will throw the error you've seen.

For sasToken, you can generate it from code or from azure portal.

Here is the sample code including generating sas token for blob:

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, BlobClient, generate_blob_sas, BlobSasPermissions
from azure.storage.fileshare import ShareClient, ShareFileClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

connection_string="xxx"

blobserviceclient = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
source_blob = BlobClient(blobserviceclient.url,container_name="xxx", blob_name="xxx")

#generate sas token for this blob
sasToken = generate_blob_sas(
    account_name="xxx",
    container_name="xxx",
    blob_name="xxxx",
    account_key="xxx",
    permission= BlobSasPermissions(read=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

fileshareclient =ShareClient.from_connection_string(connection_string,"xxx")
destination_file = fileshareclient.get_file_client('xxx')

destination_file.start_copy_from_url(source_blob.url+"?"+sasToken)

print("**copy completed**")
```